# Unable to get python xarray Dataset.drop_vars to work

Tags: python-3.x, python-xarray

I am using xarray v 0.17.0 (latest).
I can't seem to get Dataset.drop_vars() to do what it is supposed to do. Here is some example code:

```
import xarray as xr
dsxr = xr.open_dataset('a_sample.nc')
print (dsxr)

Output (trimmed):
Data variables:
    projected_x_coordinate  (x_coordinate, y_coordinate) float64 ...
    projected_y_coordinate  (x_coordinate, y_coordinate) float64 ...
    x_coordinate_1D         (x_coordinate) float64 ...
    y_coordinate_1D         (y_coordinate) float64 ...
    xvel                    (time, x_coordinate, y_coordinate) float64 ...
    yvel                    (time, x_coordinate, y_coordinate) float64 ...
    aice                    (time, x_coordinate, y_coordinate) float64 ...


dsxr.drop_vars('aice')

print (dsxr)

Output (trimmed):
Data variables:
    projected_x_coordinate  (x_coordinate, y_coordinate) float64 ...
    projected_y_coordinate  (x_coordinate, y_coordinate) float64 ...
    x_coordinate_1D         (x_coordinate) float64 ...
    y_coordinate_1D         (y_coordinate) float64 ...
    xvel                    (time, x_coordinate, y_coordinate) float64 ...
    yvel                    (time, x_coordinate, y_coordinate) float64 ...
    aice                    (time, x_coordinate, y_coordinate) float64 ...
```

The 'aice' variable is still there. Where am I going wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Assign dsxr.drop_vars('aice') to a new variable and print that new variable.

Comment: Thanks! That works, but how would one then remove multiple variables (e.g. in a loop)? I am new to SO. Should I be asking this as a separate question?

Comment: You don't need to use a loop to remove multiple variables. You can pass a list with names of variables you'd like to remove as an argument to drop_vars, so drop_vars(['variable1', 'variable2']). For information check out the documentation: https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.drop_vars.html